# How can I test json data members for length?

Tags: jquery, html, json, getjson

Based on the data I get back via `.getJSON()`, I will build up html to append to a div.

Whether certain parts are added depends on if certain members contain worthwhile values. For example, if data.bla, trimmed, is less than, say, 10 characters, I'll leave it out of the equation/won't add it to the dynamically-created html.

My pseudo jQuery is such:

```
var htmlBuilder;
....
$.getJSON()....each() {
    if (data.someURL.trim().length > 10) {
        htmlBuilder += '<a href=\"...';
    }
}
```

...but is that the preferred way to do it?

Comment: The problem itself has nothing to do with JSON or Ajax. It seems you just want to know that is the best way to trim and test the length of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fine. I'd do `var htmlBuilder = '';` though. If you do `var htmlBuilder; htmlBuilder += 'bar';` you'll get `"undefinedbar"`.

Here's what my code would look like:

```
var html = '';
$.getJSON('/path', function(results){
  $.each( results, function(i, result){
    if( $.trim(result.url.length) > 10 ){
      html += '<a href="#">Testing</a>';
    }
  });
  $('#results').append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `$.trim` instead of `.trim()` method as the latter does not work in IE 8 and below.

Also better to check for null condition before you invoke a method.

```
var str = data.someURL;
if (str && $.trim(str).length > 10) {
```